# Connecting jumper to input pin

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, jumper

I am designing an active high function in my MCU program and I need a jumper to activate/deactivate the function by placing it between Vcc and one input pin of the MCU. I have came up with two connections
[image]

[image]

Which connection is better and what is the reason behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something to pull the voltage down to GND when the jumper is removed. A pull down resistor, as in your second example, is the usual way. Some microcontrollers have a built-in pull-down resistor, but it consumes more power because it requires a FET to switch it in.

Your second example with the resistor is probably the best option, and the only one that will work unless your micro has built in pull-down resistors. Basically zero current will flow through it when the jumper is removed, and only (10*Vcc) microampres when it is fitted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would be the reading of the pin if I remove the jumper in the first example?

Comment: It would be undefined. Your second example is not better, is the only one that would work.

Comment: If you removed the jumper the pin would "float". The exact behaviour depends on the microcontroller. Some have bus keeping circuits that would hold it in one state or the other, some would just allow it to randomly vary with stray voltages on the PCB. The pin is probably high impedance, so only a small amount of current is needed to make the voltage swing around wildly.

Answer (score 0):

Without the pull-down resistor the net would be floating and you would measure random states (H or L) on it. Even if you would always see a L on the pin during development that might suddenly show up as a H due to external circumstances (i.e. noise) and cause you big headaches.